# How to do user authentication in angularjs with Spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, session-management

I am using spring MVC framework in back end as **REST(JSON/XML)**.  In front end i am using angularjs for rendering the UI.

I done with **CRUD operations** (Like get,add,update,delete). And i added the user authentication in angularjs with spring security (for logout used  **j_spring_security_logout**,for login  **j_spring_security_check**).

The Login page is .jsp file.

Actually i added the angular files inside **/WEB-INF/** folder.

For session expired i will navigate to login page. Everything is working fine. But after navigate to login page if i am doing login means it's returning **JSON Object** instead of dashboard page.(i.e Last service or API call of session, the service call made by user).

Like below.
[image: API Call JSON Object]

Please help me to do solve this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, show your security config. If you have configured login page via `<security:form-login>` tag, setting attribute `always-use-default-target="true"` will help.

Comment: Thanks @Aeteros. It's Worked.